# English Equivalent of phrase "Whose face did you see in the morning?"

Tags: phrases

In hindi, we use the above phrase (in hindi, obviously) as a response to someone having a bad day, bad luck.

e.g. -

> Person 1: I'm having a bad day. I have been followed by a velociraptor
>   the entire day.
>
> Person 2: Whoa, dude! Whose face did you see the first thing in the
>   morning?

I tried searching for the above phrase (and its variations) but did not get any result except some weird memes.

Comment: Can you give a clearer explanation of what a speaker of Hindi would understand that phrase to mean? Is it referring to looking in a mirror, seeing a ghost, seeing an actual person that somehow affected the rest of one's day negatively?

Comment: @McCaverty: It could be used to refer to seeing oneself in a mirror or another person who has caused your day, which otherwise would have been positive, to become bad.

Comment: @user96551 to make it clear, the phrase suggests that whoever you saw first is the person responsible for your bad day?

Comment: Hard to find sources, but I've heard and said "Who did you upset?", implying that the person who's suffering did something to someone (either a specific person or to fate/God/the powers that be) to invoke their punishment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is one 'go to' phrase which people use in this situation, so much as they would paraphrase various superstitions about things reputed to cause bad luck. Three which spring to mind are

- walking under a ladder
- breaking a mirror

  or
- having a black cat cross your path 
   So you might say in response to:
  *I'm having a bad day. I have been followed by a velociraptor the entire day.*

> Woah, dude! How many mirrors did you break/ladders did you walk under on your way to work?

For black cats, because it is a bit clumsy somehow to say 'Did a black cat cross your path?' many Brits might make a joke of it with 'How many black cats did you kick on your way in?'

Comment: Personally, if I encounter someone having a bad day I will ask *What did your horoscope say this morning?* But I agree with you, I don't think there is an obvious widely-used expression which covers it.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

> I got up on the wrong side of the bed this morning.

I've been unsettled or have have bad luck all day long.

Comment: Getting out of the wrong side of the bed refers to being in an ill humour, more than having bad luck. http://www.bloomsbury-international.com/en/student-ezone/idiom-of-the-week/list-of-itioms/116-get-up-on-the-wrong-side-of-the-bed.html

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate interpretations of your question, due to English, not to your question-writing skills. In (America) English, "bad day" can be interpreted to mean being in a bad mood, having bad luck, or both.

For having a bad mood, John Feltz's answer of 'getting up on the wrong side of the bed' is spot-on and usable in almost any situation.

I'll add a more colloquial and cruder alternative:

> "Who peed in your Cheerios?"

You can substitute almost any common breakfast cereal for Cheerios while keeping the exact same meaning (Fruit Loops, for example), although I ([and the Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=peed%20in%20your%20cheerios)) agree that Cheerios is the most common. I've heard some unsubstantiated rumors that Canadians say "Who pooped in your poutine?"

If you're talking about the concept of just having a day of bad luck, English has at least one specific option:

> What gypsy did you piss off?

The superstition behind this is that gypsy beggars will curse people who don't give them money or don't help them.

Comment: I've always heard this as "corn flakes" rather than Cheerios, but I'm probably older than most respondents.  But yes, this is the best match from my extensive knowledge of colloquial American English.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> Who rained on your parade?

Generally it means; who ruined or criticised your plans or aspirations.

Comment: As with getting out of the bed on the wrong side, isn't this more about the person being in a foul mood than them experiencing bad luck? Having your parade rained on would *itself* be bad luck, but it wouldn't cause more ill fortune, it would just make you grumpy.